# Linking a dynamic library (libjvm.dylib) in Mac OS X (rpath issue)

Tags: macos, haskell, linker, java-native-interface, ghc

I do have an application that requires linkage with `libjvm` (a library from the JDK needed to do JNI bindings). When I tell the location of `libjvm.dylib` using `-L` it successfully compiles and links. However when I run the binary I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: <my home directory>/./mybinary
  Reason: image not found
```

So far I found out that I can run my binary specifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to libfolder installation> ./mybinary
```

But of course I do not want that. Why should I specify the exact location anyway if I have to give it again and again each time I start the application?!

I also learned that dynamic libraries on mac os x do get a kind of stamp which tells there location. However I don't know what `rpath` is (seems like a variable to me, but how can I set it during linking?).

The application is built using haskell, but I can equally well link the object files manually using `ld`. However, I'm stuck on that rpath thing - is it maybe special to the JDK libraries?

Here is what I do in order to build:

```
ghc --make Main.hs mycbinding.o -ljvm -L<javahome>/jre/lib/server -o mybinary
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Apple's [dyld man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html):

> @rpath/
>
> ```
>   Dyld maintains a current stack of paths called the run path list.
>   When @rpath is encountered it is substituted with each path in the
>   run path list until a loadable dylib if found. The run path stack
>   is built from the LC_RPATH load commands in the depencency chain
>   that lead to the current dylib load. You can add an LC_RPATH load
>   command to an image with the -rpath option to ld(1). You can even add
>   a LC_RPATH load command path that starts with @loader_path/, and it
>   will push a path on the run path stack that relative to the image
>   containing the LC_RPATH. The use of @rpath is most useful when you
>   have a complex directory structure of programs and dylibs which can be
>   installed anywhere, but keep their relative positions. This scenario
>   could be implemented using @loader_path, but every client of a dylib
>   could need a different load path because its relative position in the
>   file system is different. The use of @rpath introduces a level of
>   indirection that simplies things. You pick a location in your directory
>   structure as an anchor point. Each dylib then gets an install path that
>   starts with @rpath and is the path to the dylib relative to the anchor
>   point. Each main executable is linked with -rpath @loader_path/zzz,
>   where zzz is the path from the executable to the anchor point. At runtime
>   dyld sets it run path to be the anchor point, then each dylib is found
>   relative to the anchor point.
> ```

You need to pass `-rpath path/containing/the/library` to `ld` when linking your binary to tell it where to search when expanding the `@rpath/` prefix in the shared library load command. With GHC you can use the `-optl-Wl` argument to have it pass flags through to `ld`, so you'll want to invoke GHC like so:

```
ghc --make Main.hs mycbinding.o -ljvm -L<javahome>/jre/lib/server -optl-Wl,-rpath,<javahome>/jre/lib/server -o mybinary
```